# Bootloader: verify user application before handover

Tags: c, microcontroller, bootloader

I am writing a second stage bootloader for SAMD21, which hands over to a userland application after hardware initialization.

How do I verify that the jump address with the application reset handler (eg `0x2000`) contains actually valid code?

The goal is to abort the jump if there is no valid userland handler to avoid undefined behaviour.

Comment: Have a magic located just below 0x2000? fixed instruction at 0x2000? :D

Comment: oh, I didn't think of putting it *below* 0x2000.. thats great! I will not have control over the instruction at 0x2000

Comment: You should be digitally signing the firmware and verifying the firmware using a public key that is stored in the ROM.  For example, read about the [Secure Boot Chain](https://www.apple.com/business/site/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf) in iOS.  This is how everybody does it, not just Apple.  Just make sure you do it right (lots of pitfalls here) or else you could suffer the same fate that [Sony suffered](https://www.engadget.com/2010/12/29/hackers-obtain-ps3-private-cryptography-key-due-to-epic-programm/).

Answer (score 0):

The bootloader should have the ability to check that the application code is valid before jumping to it.  One way is to perform a CRC over the entire application code.  Add a step to the end of your build process to calculate a CRC over the application code and insert the CRC value into the binary image at a known/reserved location.  Then at startup the bootloader performs the same CRC calculation and compares it with the CRC value embedded in the application.

For more details and ideas, see these and similar application notes

http://www.keil.com/appnotes/files/an277.pdf

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/doc1143.pdf

Comment: If you do this type of check only and no digital signatures, then there are [severe security consequences](https://www.wired.com/2011/11/hp-printer-hack/).  CRC protects against random faults only, not malicious faults.  Firmware needs to be digitally signed to prevent malicious attacks.